# Emulator Command Line Options not avaiable in Android Studio

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using 32-bit Linux operating system along with Android Studio 1.5.1 so while running Emulator i got following error:

> ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use
>   them
>          you will have to do at least one of the following:
>
> - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
> - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
>        Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
>        aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
>        Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.

I can fix this problem temporarily by adding `-force-32bit` command in Emulator Command Line Options while starting emulator from Android Studio. But i am not able to find Emulator command line options.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Here it is: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/emulator.html